# What is a catemer?

Tags: physical-chemistry, crystal-structure

What is a catemer and how does it differ from a dimer? What type of compounds could form catemers and how does their formation influence its crystal structure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the crystal, carboxylic acids mostly form dimers through pairs of $\ce{OH\bond{~}O=C}$ hydrogen bonds.

In some cases, infinite chains of hydrogen bonds are formed instead: here, each carboxylic acid forms hydrogen bonds to **two different neighbours**. These structures are known as catemers.

[image]

(*Please note that the depiction of the catemer is **very much** simplified! In reality, the structure could also be a helix, stabilized by additional sets of interactions*)

Actually, I have never used the term *catemer* in a crystallographic publication. It is very imprecise, almost meaningless. Instead, I have mostly used the a notation introduced by *Margret C. Etter* to describe hydrogen bonding pattern (dimers, stands, rings) in a crystal.

Two relevant articles in this context are:

1. Encoding and decoding hydrogen-bond patterns of organic compounds,
   *Acc. Chem. Res.*, **1990**, *23*, 120-126 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ar00172a005))
2. Graph-set analysis of hydrogen-bond patterns in organic crystals, *Acta Cryst. B*, **1990**, *46*, 256-262 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1107/S0108768189012929))

Comment: A good explanation of the various structures can be found in this paper: http://www.academia.edu/7596281/Crystal_Packing_Hydrogen_Bonding_and_the_Effect_of_Crystal_Forces_on_Molecular_Conformation