# Could a 'polymer' be formed by hydrogen bonding?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

For example, given you had a molecule with a carboxyl functional group on either side, could it form a continuous chain of dimers? I understand this may not fit under the definition for polymer but I lack better terminology to describe such a thing. For Example:[image: Carboxyl Dimer Polymer]

Alternatively;[image: Alternatively]

Comment: Yeah, why not? The appropriate term for this is "catemers". See the answer to these questions: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138865/why-dont-dicarboxylic-acids-show-hydrogen-bonding-in-spite-of-the-fact-that-car ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28897/what-is-a-catemer/28899#28899

Comment: The two strands of DNA are largely held together by H bonds.

Comment: The water ice can be seen as such polymer.

Comment: The crystal structure of KHCO3 contains H-bond based HCO3- dimers, while for NaHCO3 there are HCO3- polymers. Or vice versa, I am not sure now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a polymer is a

> "molecule of high relative molecular mass, the structure of which essentially comprises the multiple repetition of units derived, actually or conceptually, from molecules of low relative molecular mass." ([IUPAC Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/M03667))

joining two *monomers* into a *dimer* is just a specific wording for the more general term *polymer* like it is for trimer, tetramer, pentamer, hexamer, etc.  While the term *polymers* often is used about plastics, cellulose, starch, or chitin equally are polymers, too.  Note, this definition does constraint the binding of the monomers to covalent bonds.

The depictions shown as examples by you are valid representations when describing, e.g., the hydrogen-bond pattern in organic crystals.  Here, hydrogen bond *donors* and hydrogen bond *acceptors* may contribute significantly to the overall stabilization of the supramolecule an organic crystal may be considered.  Magaret C. Etter and Joel Bernstein popularized  formalisms to identify *and* systematically describe these pattern.

The one described by you matches for example the situation for $p$-terephthalic acid yielding (in principle) infinite bands hold by the motif $R^2_2(8)$ (a *ring* of *eight* atoms in total, comprising *2* donor, and *2* acceptors):

[image]

([1990AccChemRes120](https://doi.org/10.1021/ar00172a005), includes a guide how to define these graph sets)

This approach equally may be extended to describe the interactions if the monomers are chemically different:

[image]

($R^2_4(8)$ motif about the interaction of phosphine / arsine oxides and  nitroanilines in co-crystals, reviewed in [1995ACIE1555](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.199515551))