# Why would a mixture of sucrose, propionic acid, sodium formate, and agar turn light blue? What reaction is happening?

Tags: acid-base

I made 3 mixtures which had 1 M sucrose, 1% w/v agar, .68% v/v propionic acid, and EITHER 0%, 4%, or 13% w/v sodium formate salt.

It was NOT blue at first, but after a couple hours at RT, the 0% sodium formate mixture was clear, the 4% mixture was barely blue, and the 13% was light blue.

**I'm wondering what reaction is likely happening here to make it blue?**

Clearly the formate is key. Perhaps some acid-base reaction? Formic acid is stronger than propionic acid, if that helps.

I'm concerned about unwanted byproducts affecting my experiments. Thx!

EDIT to answer a question: the solution became a gel almost immediately, as desired. I'm actually not sure if it was blue at that point, but it was definately NOT blue before the agar was added.

EDIT: more context: I don't care about the quality of the gel – I don't need it for blotting or anything like that, just for feeding fruit flies. So I'm trying to make sure that the ingredients I want in it are still in it, and with no NEW ones.

Comment: Perhaps growing of living stuff?

Comment: After mixing the ingredients, you obtained a solution.  After x hours of additional waiting, you got a) still a solution, or b) a gel?  What is the difference of the pristine solution with the aged "blend", is do you observe [Tyndall scattering](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effet_Tyndall) like in the cell on the [right](https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/442107/view/tyndall-effect) here?  (It is a guess, because of the presence of agar-agar.)

Comment: It is known that the solidification of agar is pH dependent. The propionic acid is probably bringing it down too much. Needs to be above 5 typically to get a good gel. Then the formate salt is raising the pH back up slightly and getting you closer to the necessary pH for gel to form, so you're getting a bit of scattering as buttonwood suggested. Try repeating the experiment but adjust the pH of all three to 5.5 with NaOH and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far! I added some clarifying edits above...Is it safe to say that the ingredients I added are probably still there, and with no NEW products?

Comment: Smaller fragments of agar-agar polymerized to form a gel / a network (think mousse au chocolat, pudding, or gel derived from tetramethoxysilane).  Establishing new chemical bonds equates formation of new compounds; thus there are new products in the container.

Comment: @Buttonwood that should be the answer. Is likely Tyndall effect and not the growing of some coloured bacteria or fungi :)) as I have first suggest as a remote possibility.

Comment: Thx @Buttonwood. Any idea what those new products might BE, specifically? Are you saying they're probably just agar-agar polymers?

Comment: Did you determine the pH of the media? Was any coloring agent added? Were all the ingredients used pure? What is their origin? Did you prepare the media?

Comment: @Alchimista Following your suggest, I edited the comment into an answer.

Comment: @Buttonwood In contrast to polyacrylamide gels, there is no covalent bond formation when agar gels. You can melt and gel agar multiple times, it is a physical process (with non-covalent bonds forming and breaking, of course). Here is a nice [write-up](https://www.scienceofcooking.com/chemical_physical_properties_agar.htm).

Comment: @KarstenTheis So there isn't a change in the network of hydrogen bonds the answer below attributes to the formation of the gel?

Comment: @Buttonwood I classify hydrogen bonds as non-covalent, and they do change as I said in the parenthetical remark in my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

Agar-agar consists of polysaccharides; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar) for example mentions *agarose*:

[image]

([credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar#Composition))

As with many naturally occurring polymers, the degree of polymerization (i.e., the repeating number of building blocks per polymer chain) varies.  Any form of processing may increase the variation with shorter and longer chains of this polymer.

The hydroxyl groups may interact with hydroxyl groups of the same polymer chain, as well as with other polymer chains by hydrogen bonds (see, e.g., a previous answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151885/could-a-polymer-be-formed-by-hydrogen-bonding/151955#151955)) which contributes to optimize the intermolecular interactions / lowering the overall energy.  Despite different in chemical nature, *conceptually* there are similarities to proteins: in addition to the primary structure (a chain of building blocks form a chain), there is conformational flexibility around the glycosidic bond to yield a secondary structure.

Similar to gelatin in the kitchen, bringing the polymer chains of agar-agar into water allows these chains to re-adjust their conformation.  The hydroxyl groups of agar-agar now equally interact with water molecules to minimize the overall energy of the system.  The formation of new loops and pockets is possible in which water molecules are trapped.  These cavities may be formed by one, or multiple polymer chains.  In an analogy, think about cooked spaghetti (the agar-agar chains) and the much smaller grains of carbonara (the trapped water molecules); *except* for the example of agar-agar, the number of water molecules is much larger, than the about the agar-agar molecules.

The then again solidified agar-agar is like a frozen state: the polymer chains are locked in each other, shorter and longer ones.  Thus the size of the pockets including water, as well of local volumes with some degree of order vary.  This order is *like* crystallinity; though unlikely as nicely ordered like in a crystal of NaCl, there is *some* regularity at the scale of visible light (about $400-\pu{750 nm}$) causing diffraction and scattering.  At this scale of length, it is equally known as [Tyndall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect):

> «[...which] is similar to Rayleigh scattering, in that the intensity of the scattered light is inversely proportional to the fourth power of the wavelength, so *blue light is scattered much more strongly than red light*.» ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect), emphasis added.)

Thus the light blueish appearance, equally seen with gels of other chemical composition:

[image]

([credit](https://news.itmo.ru/en/science/new_materials/news/8722/))

For polymers, the analysis of the light scattering allows to infer e.g., [particle size](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed029p15#), molecular weight, or [degree of crystallinity](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/pol.20200027).

Comment: It turns out the medium in question is used to feed fruit flies, and sometimes a *blue* coloring agent is added to such media. This introduces ambiguity in the OPs post since the person has not answered in more detail what went into the growth medium. Good answer though!